# C# winform, is it a good idea to have all Related Classes Partial?

Tags: c#, winforms

I my Main Form, there are two buttons that will display other Forms
(each button displays a single new form)
now, my main form class name is MyMainForm ..
The other two forms class names are: MySubForm1 , MySubForm2
the problem is that I'm having some trouble accessing some of the stuff in MyMainForm
inside of the sub forms ..

Is it a good idea to have them all partial ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what a "subform" is?  Is it just another form that you're displaying?  A dialog?  A "document" form in an MDI application? Partial classes would not be appropriate here if any of the above are true.

Comment: you can use user control in order to separate your design ( or your main window) view this article : http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html

Comment: yes, it's just a form that I'm displaying it's System.Windows.Forms.Form

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of information you want to pass back and forth?

Comment: Actually, there are 3 textBoxes in my mainForm that I wanna access from the subform, So I came up with an idea, I made a method to change theses textboxes (this method is in myMainForm class)
then, I added it to a delegate and passed the delegate to the constructor of the 2nd form ..
I don't know whether that's good or not ..
But I just I want a better way of doing this ..
If I make the subForms partial, I would be able to access the textboxes in the mainform, so my Q is that a good thing ?

Comment: I wouldn't change the constructor of your form to have arguments. Causes problems. If the values won't change when you create the new form it would be a better idea to use properties on the second form. I'll update my answer accordingly in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are expecting to be able to access private members of a form from a different form.

You need to have a reference from the "SubForms" to the parent form should you wish to be able to access any of its members.

Secondly, you won't be able to access "private" members. Again two options, either create public get/set methods for the members you want, or alternatively change the access modifier of objects to public/internal.

Post some more code explaining what you have tried and what you are trying to achieve and I may be able to point you in the correct direction.

Also, in more direct response to your question, partials have nothing to do with what you are trying to do, they are for extending existing classes whilst maintaining separation of code in logical files.

```
public class Main : Form
{
     // assuming here you have three textboxes

     private void button1_Click(eventargs etc)
     {
         OtherForm otherForm = new OtherForm() { Text1 = textbox1.Text, 
                                                 Text2 = textbox2.Text,
                                                 Text3 = textbox3.Text };
         otherForm.Show();
     }

}

public class OtherForm : Form
{
    public String Text1 { get; set; }
    public String Text2 { get; set; }
    public String Text3 { get; set; }
}
```

With this setup, your OtherForm has a copy of the text values as they were at the time of the forms creation.

By the sounds of your question and following comments, this is what you expect in your scenario, but I will say again, show us some code and we can help better. Partials is definately not the right answer.